# How to read content of all files in the folder and in the sub directories

Tags: java

How to read content of all files in the folder and in the sub directories. I wrote the method, which get all paths of all files in the folder and in the sub directories. How can I read content of all files by getpath?

```
 public static void pathFiles(File folder) {
            File[] folderEntries = folder.listFiles();
            for (File entry : folderEntries) {
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    processFilesFromFolder(entry);
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println(entry.getPath());
            }
        }
```

I think to use the `getTextFromFile()`, but it get String.

```
public static String getTextFromFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(fileName)));
```

Answer (score 0):

For every file which you found use:

```
Files.lines(entry.getPath()).forEach(System.out::println);
```

where `entry.getPath()` is path to file.

Take a look: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#lines-java.nio.file.Path-

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SimpleFileVisitor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) and [Files.lines](https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-stream-read-a-file-line-by-line/)

```
  static class ClassPrinter extends SimpleFileVisitor<Path>{
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
            Files.lines(file).forEach(System.out::println);
            return super.visitFile(file, attrs);
        }
    }
```

This will recursively scan a directory, and on each file, it will print it's content.